# declarative auth problem with if_attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, declarative-authorization

my authorization rules:

```
role :tester do
  has_permission_on [:regression_test_test_runs, :regression_test_jobs], :to => :manage
  has_permission_on [:authorization_rules], :to => [:read, :manage]
  has_permission_on [:users], :to => :edit do
    if_attribute :user => is {user}
  end
end
```

my users controller

```
filter_access_to :all, :attribute_check => true
```

why is it that i still get a permission denied? i've tried playing around and i still can't get the current user, which is a tester to edit his own profile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to change your authorization rules to:

```
role :tester do
  ...
  has_permission_on [:users], :to => :edit do
    if_attribute :id => is {user.id}
  end
end
```

I'm guessing that user doesn't have an attribute named user, that's why your original example was failing. You'll have to compare the user's id against the current user's id instead.